# Xamarin Forms XAML OnPlatform VerticalOptions

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, vertical-alignment

What I'm trying to do may seem to be simple but I have been looking for around an hour with no luck so far.

I have the following XAML

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Margin="20,20,20,20">
    <StackLayout.VerticalOptions>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="EndAndExpand" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </StackLayout.VerticalOptions>
</StackLayout>
```

But it's giving an error saying:

```
Cannot assign property VerticalOptions, property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property
```

I have done the same successfully but for other properties of type x:Boolean, x:Double and Thickness... Out of curiosity I've been also trying to find some documentation that outlines all the available x:TypeArguments as a reference but still with no luck as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is in this line

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
```

You are saying that the value is a String however it's a `LayoutOptions` type. So changing this, it works:

```
<StackLayout Margin="20,20,20,20">
    <StackLayout.VerticalOptions>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="LayoutOptions">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="EndAndExpand" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </StackLayout.VerticalOptions>
</StackLayout>
```

In the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.View.VerticalOptions/) you can see that `VerticalOption` is a `LayoutOption`:

> Syntax
>
> public LayoutOptions VerticalOptions { get; set; }
>
> Value
>
> A LayoutOptions which defines how to lay out the element. Default value is LayoutOptions.Fill unless otherwise documented.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks alot. I always had this confusion with each XAML type argument I write but you made it much easier